# Why DateTime.Now save to SQL YYYY-DD-MM in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I tried save DateTime.Now to SQL but column data created like this

```
2014-06-02 22:30:19.000
```

But I want it to be like

```
2014-02-06 22:30:19.000
```

or

```
06-02-2014 22:30:19.000
```

My codes:

```
conn.Open();
var commandSQL= new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO TableName(SaveTime) 
values (@SaveTime) ", conn);
commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("SaveTime",DateTime.Now.ToString());   
commandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You should store it as a DateTime, not text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` in .Net framework and SQL Server doesn't have any format. You should add the `DateTime` object directly instead of calling `ToString`

Just remove the `ToString` when adding value with parameter

```
commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaveTime",DateTime.Now);
```

*(You are missing @ with your parameter, but I don't think that is the issue here)*

Format is only useful for displaying purpose.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is perfectly happy to take a string value for any data type, provided there is an [implicit conversion defined from string to that datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), viz:

[image: SQL Server T-SQL data type conversion table]

So...

**What is the data type of your column `SaveTime`?**

If it is `datetime`, `smalldatetime`, `datetime2` or `date`, it means that you're converting a CLR `DateTime` to a string, which is then converted to the SQL Server datatype with the precision implicit with that datatype. And, it has not representation until you give it one. Further, there is a  possible loss of precision: the finest precision of the resulting SQL Server value is limited by the implicit precision of the string representation you sent to SQL Server.

If the column's data type is something else — `char`, `nchar`, `varchar`, `nvarchar` — it will be stored exactly as the string representation you sent up to SQL Server, with all that implies. When you convert a C# `System.DateTime` to a string, the default conversion format used is dependent upon the current value of [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the thread upon which the conversion is performed.

Just add the C# `DateTime` value directly as the value of the parameter: you don't need to convert it to a string. Let the infrastructure do the work for you.